# Laravel query builder binding parameters more than once

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, binding

I'm trying to bind the same value to some parameter in a raw query (Laravel 5.2)

```php
//this is a non practical example ,only for clarify the question

DB::table('users as u')
->select('id')
->whereRaw('u.id > ? or u.id < ? or u.id = ?',[$id, $id, $id])
->first();
```

is there any way to bind the same parameters at once(prevent duplicating values in `[$id, $id, $id]`)?

Comment: Do you always know many placeholders there will be, or do you want to fill all placeholders in the query with the same value, no matter how many there are?

Comment: In the case of mine ,I know how many placeholder  will be there,and specially in this example **all** of them are the same too. i tried  `:=someparameter` or `:someparameter` to separate placeholders by the name ,but it doesn't work.seems only `?` is valid!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `whereRaw`? Would an answer which rewrites it without `whereRaw` be valid?

Answer (score 21):

Use named parameters. They're covered in the documentation in the [Running Raw SQL Queries section of the Database page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries), under the subheading Using Named Bindings. Quoting:

> Instead of using `?` to represent your parameter bindings, you may execute a query using named bindings:
>
> ```
> $results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
> ```

In your case you ought to be able to run this:

```
DB::table('users as u')
    ->select('id')
    ->whereRaw('u.id > :id or u.id < :id or u.id = :id', [
        'id' => 2,
    ])
    ->first();
```

But it seems Laravel throws a `QueryException` with the message `Invalid parameter number`. I've reported this as [a bug](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12715).

If you really want to use `whereRaw` you could instead build your array of parameters from a variable:

```
$id = 2;
DB::table('users as u')
    ->select('id')
    ->whereRaw('u.id > ? or u.id < ? or u.id = ?', [
        $id, $id, $id,
    ])
    ->first();
```

Or use [`array_fill`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to repeat the value for you:

```
$id = 2;
DB::table('users as u')
    ->select('id')
    ->whereRaw('u.id > ? or u.id < ? or u.id = ?', array_fill(0, 3, $id))
    ->first();
```

If you don't need `whereRaw` you can instead use other features of the query builder and build the query bit by bit, with the parameter coming from a variable:

```
$id = 2;
DB::table('users')
    ->select('id')
    ->where('id', '>', $id)
    ->orWhere('id', '<', $id)
    ->orWhere('id', $id)
    ->first();
```

The query builder is quite powerful, and to get more complicated logic you can nest closures. See the [relevant section of the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses) for some examples.

Comment: thanks.but it doesnt work .you cant use same name parameter in a query .just test this: `$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id or id > :id', ['id' => 1]);` it will throw an exception

Comment: Interesting. That looks like a Laravel bug to me. I reported it on the tracker as [laravel/framework#12715](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12715). I'll update the answer's first half to reflect this. But what about the second half?

Comment: I was thought laravel named parameter binding is like PHP's. seems i was wrong or maybe its a bug as you said.your answer second half  is what i'm using , that's ok! waiting for the bug report reply...

Comment: You cannot use the same parameter multiple times. Also, make sure the order is the same: for example `DB::select('select * from users where id = :id2 or id > :id1', ['id1' => 1, 'id2' => 2])` will bind `id2=1` and `id2=1`

Comment: @ursuleacv, did you read the whole answer? Also, I think there's a typo in your code snippet. Assuming you meant to type "`id2=1` and `id1=2`", that sounds like another bug -- is that a bug in Laravel or where?

Comment: @tremby, Yes you are right I meant `id2=1` and `id1=2`. I think when binding, Laravel will disregard the names and will create an array like `[0=>1, 1=>2]`

Comment: @ursuleacv, have you tested to back that up? I would have thought that's definitely another Laravel bug if so.

Comment: @tremby, I am converting a project from Yii to Laravel and got wrong results from a query. Then I noticed this strange behavior. I don't have time now. I will try in weekends to reproduce the bug.

Comment: `array_fill` was very elegant. In my scenario, I had multiple query statements and different amounts of binding parameters of the same value. So I used  `substr_count` to match the '?' in my query and use the result in the `array_fill` eg: `$c = substr_count($query, "?"); array_fill(0, $c, $amt]));`

Comment: @bishop did named parameters not work? Did they still not fix that bug? (...edit...) actually reading that thread again I'm not really clear on whether it ended up being a bug or not. Still, I'd prefer named parameters if it's possible to use them, over counting question marks. I'd worry that a question mark could crop up somehow in a query which *isn't* a placeholder.

Comment: @tremby no named parameters did not work for me. In my scenario, I am using the same parameter twice in a single SQL statement and getting an erorr! I think you were right in that it should be a [bug](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12715#issuecomment-197013236).

Answer (score 1):

As @tremby has answered, You can use

```php
DB::table('users as u')
  ->select('id')
  ->whereRaw('u.id > :id or u.id < :id or u.id = :id',['id'=>2])
  ->first();
```

to use named binding.

Additionally, You have to set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true` in `config/database.php` in order to get rid of the `Invalid parameter number` exception, like:

`config/database.php`

```php
'mysql' => [
  'driver'    => 'mysql',
  ...
  'options' => [
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
  ],
],
```

Reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12715#issuecomment-197013236

Comment: As stated in the reference link you provided this method will open a _can of worms_ as it will inevitably break your Laravel app in parts you may not be aware of!