# Dynamically generate query with diff number of "where"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I dynamically generate query to the db if I don't know how much **filter** and **update** -  values will be in the **$filters** and **$updates** arrays?
Template of the query is below:

```
$model::where($key_1, '=', $filter1)
    ->where($key_2, '=', $filter_2)
    ->where($key_n, '=', $filter_n)
    ->update([$key_1 => $update_1,
        $key_2 => $update_2,
        $key_n => $update_n
    ]);
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968797/1779433

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple where clause query using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: You could use a `foreach` loop. Alternatively, depending on their structure, `where` can accept an array of arguments. Post your filter and update arrays.

Answer (score 0):

loop through your arrays and call each method per filter:

```
foreach($filters as $key =>$value){
   $model->where($key, $value);
}
```

and then build your `$updates` array in the same way and call update:

```
$model->update($updates);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use and recommend query scopes.
It keeps your code clean and readable while you can reuse code also.

In my model `User` I would create a function called `scopeFilter`

```
public function scopeFilter($query, $params)
{
    if(isset($params['status']) && trim($params['status']) !== '')
    {
        $query->where('status', '=', trim($params['status']));
    }

    if(isset($params['is_admin']) && is_bool($params['is_admin']))
    {
        $query->where('is_admin', '=', $params['is_admin'] ? '1' : '0');
    }
    return $query;
}
```

In my `ApiUsersController` I would just use this call, note that word `scope` is omitted when making the call.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::filter($request->all())->get();

    return Response::make([
        'success' => true,
        'data'    => $users
        ]);
}
```

Now in your case, you can have a loop in `scopeFilter` something like following

```
foreach ($params as $key->$param) {
    $query->where($key, '=', $param);
}
```

This is to give you an idea how I do it and it keeps the code clean.

Also please read **Local Scopes** in Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes). IMHO it is cleanest way to achieve filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter grouping:

```
$model::where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
            foreach($filters as $filter) {
                $query->where($filter->column, '>', $filter->value);
            }
            return $query;
        })
```

...